# Trivial geometry question about an angle between two parallel blocks (CG)

Tags: geometry

Trivial but not for me.
See the figure below. I'd like to draw a kind of "N" where the thickness of the 3 segments is variable.
From "r" the ratio of the thickness over the side of the square, how to find the value of "α", the angle of the inclined segment?

[image]

(Edit: every segment has a thickness of "r")

Comment: (If the thickness of the inclined segment is also $r$) Between the two vertical segments, the inclined segment forms a parallelogram, whose vertical sides have length $\frac r{\sin\alpha}$. Consider one of the white triangles, its vertical side has length $\frac{1-2r}{\tan\alpha}$. 

$$\frac{r}{\sin\alpha} + \frac{1-2r}{\tan\alpha} = 1$$

From [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+α+in+r%2F%28sin+α%29+%2B+%281-2r%29%2F%28tan+α%29+%3D+1) apparently it's a quadratic equation in $\tan\frac\alpha2$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comment by @peterwhy, one needs to solve the equation

$$\frac{r}{\sin\alpha}+\frac{1-2r}{\tan\alpha}=1$$

Upon rearrangement we get

$$\sin\alpha-(1-2r)\cos\alpha=r\iff \sin(\alpha-\delta)=\frac{r}{1+(1-2r)^2}$$

where $\sin\delta:=(1-2r)/\sqrt{1+(1-2r)^2}$. This can  now be solved quite easily to yield the unique solution

$$\alpha(r)=\sin^{-1}\frac{r}{\sqrt{1+(1-2r)^2}}+\sin^{-1}\frac{1-2r}{\sqrt{1+(1-2r)^2}}$$

We find that

$$\alpha(1/5)=40.84^\circ~,~ \alpha(2/5)=34.40^\circ$$

and also $\alpha(0)=\pi/4$ which works a sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From your figure, the width of central narrow white rectangle $=(1-2r) $

Lengths of red and green line segments when added is 1.

$$r/\sin \alpha + ( 1-2r)  \tan \alpha =1 $$

If $ t= \tan(\alpha/2) $ we have

$$r\frac{1+t^2}{2t}+(1-2r) \frac{1-t^2}{2t} =1 $$
simplifies to a quadratic equation

$$ t^2( 3r-1) -2t +(1-r)=0 $$

which can be solved as

$$ \tan ( \alpha/2)=\frac {\sqrt{3r^2-4r+2}-1}{(1-3r)}$$

with proper sign before sqrt radical. When $r=0$ it should check $ \alpha /2=22.5^{\circ}
\text{  from }  t^2+2t -1 =0, $

which checks alright.